# Remove -ing from words in a file

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to remove all -ing from a file with sed.

i.e. joking should become jok , trailing should become trail

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What about something like "sing"?  Should it just become "s"?

Comment: Guys your solution are wrong I answered my question. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your question was a little bit vague. Besides, did you new the solution before you asked?

Comment: No I found in here http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html search for "ending in -ing" . Nevermin your solution looks corect I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ echo "foo joking bar bazinger" | sed 's/ing\>//g'
foo jok bar bazinger
```

`\>` is a boundary boundary between word and nonword character. So `bazinger` is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ing\>//f'
```

The above matches all words ending with `ing`.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but probably with something like this:

```
sed -i 's/ing//g' path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/ing//g' your_file
```

use the above command

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\Bing\b//g' file
```

or

```
sed ' s/\([^ ]\)ing\>/\1/g' file
```